# Sequelize create method is ignoring validation rules

Tags: javascript, node.js, validation, model, sequelize.js

I am building a small REST API with node, hapi and sequelize. When attempting to create a new user without the required data, I expect validation errors. Instead, I receive database errors.

The model:

```
'use strict';
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
  var User = sequelize.define('User',
    {
      email: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        validate: {notEmpty: true, isEmail: true}
      },
      password: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        validate: {notEmpty: true, min: 6}
      },
      name: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        validate: {notEmpty: true}
      },
      is_active: {
        type: DataTypes.BOOLEAN
      },
      api_key: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        validate: {notEmpty: true}
      }
    },
    {
      classMethods: {
        associate: function(models) {
          // associations can be defined here
          User.hasMany(models.Keeper);
        }
      },
      timestamps: true,
      createdAt: 'created',
      updatedAt: 'modified',
      deletedAt: false
    }
  );
  return User;
};
```

The code:

```
exports.users = {
  /* ... */
  create: function(req, reply) {
    models.User.create(req.payload)
      .then(function(err, user) {
        /* ... */
      })
      .catch(function(err) {
        console.log(err);
      });
    reply('test');
  },
  /* ... */
};
```

The error:

```
{ [SequelizeDatabaseError: ER_NO_DEFAULT_FOR_FIELD: Field 'password' doesn't have a default value]
  name: 'SequelizeDatabaseError',
  message: 'ER_NO_DEFAULT_FOR_FIELD: Field \'password\' doesn\'t have a default value',
  parent:
   { [Error: ER_NO_DEFAULT_FOR_FIELD: Field 'password' doesn't have a default value]
     code: 'ER_NO_DEFAULT_FOR_FIELD',
     errno: 1364,
     sqlState: 'HY000',
     index: 0,
     sql: 'INSERT INTO `Users` (`id`,`email`,`modified`,`created`) VALUES (DEFAULT,\'email@email.com\',\'2015-04-24 04:35:49\',\'2015-04-24 04:35:49\');' },
  original:
   { [Error: ER_NO_DEFAULT_FOR_FIELD: Field 'password' doesn't have a default value]
     code: 'ER_NO_DEFAULT_FOR_FIELD',
     errno: 1364,
     sqlState: 'HY000',
     index: 0,
     sql: 'INSERT INTO `Users` (`id`,`email`,`modified`,`created`) VALUES (DEFAULT,\'email@email.com\',\'2015-04-24 04:35:49\',\'2015-04-24 04:35:49\');' },
  sql: 'INSERT INTO `Users` (`id`,`email`,`modified`,`created`) VALUES (DEFAULT,\'email@email.com\',\'2015-04-24 04:35:49\',\'2015-04-24 04:35:49\');' }
```

I'm expecting a validation error for not passing a password, instead I'm getting a SQL error. Halp!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Validation will only happen if a value is already set for the field. So if the password field is null, the validation won't run.

To fix this, set `allowNull` on the column:

```
  password: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING,
    allowNull: false,
    validate: {notEmpty: true, min: 6}
  },
```

Comment: This ended up being the issue, much appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

The .catch() function you are using seems to be used in 'Database synchronization' according to the documentation. Since you already have the err parameter and the callback in your 'then' function, place your console log statement there. Like so:

```
/* ... */
create: function(req, reply) {
    models.User.create(req.payload)
      .then(function(err, user) {
        if (err){
          console.log(err);
        }
      })
    reply('test');
  },
/* ... */
```

The 'then' function is already 'catching' the validation errors if any.